# Cisco BPDUGUARD and BDPUFILTER

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-catalyst, stp

What happen if I have both ENABLED spanning-tree BPDUFILTER and BPBDUGUARD on a specific port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place a switch-port into this configuration:

```
spanning-tree bpdufilter enable
spanning-tree bpduguard enable
```

bpdufilter will take precedence and bpdugard will not be functional.

Cisco documentaion [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2970/software/release/12.1_14_ea1/configuration/guide/swstpopt.html) confims this with this statement

> "You can override the setting of the
>   no spanning-tree portfast bpdufilter
>   default global configuration command
>   by using the spanning-tree bpdufilter
>   enable interface configuration
>   command."